# Pytest with multiprocessing lock not working as expected when running tests in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, mutex, pytest-xdist

I am trying to run my pytests in parallel using the pytest plugins **parallel-0.1.1 and xdist-3.2.1** along with the **--tests-per-worker n** flag. I have a set of tests that require a preprocessing step which must be run in a critical section. This section is protected by a multiprocessing lock to avoid simultaneous execution by multiple workers.

However, despite using the lock, the workers enter the critical section simultaneously, leading to synchronization problems.

Here is a simplified version of the problematic code:

**Test code:**

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("preprocess", ["config1"], indirect=True)
def test_example1(preprocess):
    # Use the preprocessed data in the test
    print(f"Test using preprocessed data: {preprocess}")
    # do something with preprocess

@pytest.mark.parametrize("preprocess", ["config2"], indirect=True)
def test_example2(preprocess):
    # Use the preprocessed data in the test
    print(f"Test using preprocessed data: {preprocess}")
    # do something with preprocess
```

**conftest.py file:**

```
import pytest
import multiprocessing
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

@pytest.fixture
def preprocess(request):
    with lock:
        # critical section
```

Why is my lock not preventing simultaneous entry into the critical section when running the tests in parallel? How can I resolve this synchronization problem?

I appreciate any assistance with this matter!

Comment: I think that at the point you're creating your `Lock` object your tests are *already* running in multiple processes (so you're creating multiple locks, rather than a single lock that would be useful for coordination).

Comment: I thought about that but i think the lock created statically, and shared for all the tests. And the flags test per worker defiend how many threads to run so i run in one process and n threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library such as https://pypi.org/project/fasteners/ has better locking mechanisms for the goal you're trying to accomplish. You want a lock based around a file so that different processes don't create different locks.

```py
import fasteners

lock = fasteners.InterProcessLock('path/to/lock.file')

with lock:
    ... # exclusive access
```

Then your code becomes thread-safe / process-safe.

Comment: What will happen if different processes will try to create lock in the same path?

Comment: Not a problem. Only one process will be able to have access at a time. Other processes will have to wait until the active lock leaves the `with` block.